# Matlab - Matrix Function with an Independent Variable?

Tags: matrices, matlab

I'm trying create a function that returns a matrix containing a variable "l" which is an independent variable to be swept for a plot later on.

I would calculate "phi" based on user inputs which include "n" and "d", then I would use "n", "d", and "phi" to find "a", "b", "c", and "d" to create a matrix "m" with. This matrix "m" will be a function of "l".

```
phi = 2*pi*n*d/l;
a = cos(phi);
b = 1i*sin(phi)/n;
c = 1i*n*sin(phi);
d = cos(phi);
m = [a b;c d];
```

I'm really not enjoying Matlab's coding style as compared to C++ and Python... How would you guys implement this functionality?

Summary: I want a function that returns a matrix which contains an independent variable to be swept for a plot later.

Comment: This question may be better suited for stackoverflow.

Comment: Okay, I'll try over there.

Answer (score 1):

**Just to clearing out of the unanswered list!**

You can define either a handle with `@` or you can wrap up what you did as a function simply by

```
function [ mout ] = m_of_l( lin )
phi = 2*pi*n*d/lin ;
mout = [cos(phi) 1i*sin(phi)/n;1i*n*sin(phi) cos(phi)];
end
```

Later, you can use `M = m_of_l(2*pi)` to evaluate it at $l=2\pi$.